# Separate frequencies using Python and write values as many times (7895 7895 7895 7895) instead of (4*7895)

Tags: python, text-files, frequency

I'm a basic Python user and I have a large text data file (OUT2.txt) which has many values written as `2*150` meaning there are two 150 values (150 150) or `4*7895` meaning four 7895 values ( 7895 7895 7895 7895). I want to change all these types of values into values next to each other, meaning 7895 7895 7895 7895 instead of 4*7895.

Tried this code but get the error of:

```
**parts = fl.split()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'**

fl = open('OUT2.txt', 'r').readlines()
parts = fl.split()
lst = []
for part in parts:
    _parts = part.split('*')
    if len(_parts) == 1:
        lst.append(_parts[0])
    else:
        times = int(_parts[0])
        for i in range(times):
            lst.append(_parts[1])
open('OUT.3.txt','w+').writelines(lst)
```

Any suggestions please. Thanks.

**FROM THIS-EXAMPLE OF TEXT DATA FILE**

```
2*8.17997 723.188 4*33.33 3*11.0524 380.811 149.985 5*13.9643 22.8987 76.2205 2*24.7059 64.821
```

**INTO THIS**

```
8.17997 8.17997 723.188 33.33 33.33 33.3 3 33.33 11.0524 11.0524 11.0524 and so on...
```

Comment: Looks right so far. Then check each word for a "multiplication" and add it to a list either directly or after processing the multiplication.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for your answer, I tried doing that but I can't seem to get it, any code suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Link to exact same question, asked 5 hours earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64693798/how-to-separate-out-frequencies-of-values-2150-and-write-values-individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    out_lines = []
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for l in lines:
        parts = l.split()
        lst = []
        for part in parts:
            _parts = part.split('*')
            if len(_parts) == 1:
                lst.append(_parts[0])
            else:
                times = int(_parts[0])
                for i in range(times):
                    lst.append(_parts[1])
        out_lines.append(' '.join(lst))
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for line in out_lines:
        f1.write(line + '\n')
```

in.txt

```
2*8.17997 723.188 4*33.33 3*11.0524 380.811 149.985 5*13.9643 22.8987 76.2205 2*24.7059 64.821
10*8.17997 723.188 4*33.33 3*11.0524 380.811 149.985 5*13.9643 22.8987 76.2205 2*24.7059 64.821
```

out.txt

```
8.17997 8.17997 723.188 33.33 33.33 33.33 33.33 11.0524 11.0524 11.0524 380.811 149.985 13.9643 13.9643 13.9643 13.9643 13.9643 22.8987 76.2205 24.7059 24.7059 64.821
8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 8.17997 723.188 33.33 33.33 33.33 33.33 11.0524 11.0524 11.0524 380.811 149.985 13.9643 13.9643 13.9643 13.9643 13.9643 22.8987 76.2205 24.7059 24.7059 64.821
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion, how it would change if instead of inserting the values as (data=) I want the code to take the data from a text file, maybe f = open('out.txt') and then to write it out to another text file after doing the changes (out2.txt). Thanks!

Comment: @Alex8798 0 I think you can take it from here. Just see how to read/write text files in python.

Comment: I have an AttributeError . I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: `fl` is a list of lines (strings). You need to loop over the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, split on `*` and transform back into a string

```
s = "2*8.17997 723.188 4*33.33 3*11.0524 380.811 149.985 5*13.9643 22.8987 76.2205 2*24.7059 64.821"

# split the string
l = s.split()

# split on "*"
l = [x.split('*') for x in l]

# multiply recurring values, keep the single ones
l = [x[0] if len(x) == 1 else " ".join([x[1]] * int(x[0])) for x in l]

# join back to a string
result = " ".join(l)
```

If an item does not have a `*` it is simply kept as a string (`x[0]` because `split("*")` will have returned a single element list). If it does then `split("*")` will have returned 2 values, the first one `x[0]` needs to be parsed to an int and `[x[1]] * i` is a list of `i` repeating items which are joined on an white space :

```
>>> ["11.883"] * 4
["11.883", "11.883", "11.883", "11.883"]
>>> " ".join(["11.883"] * 4)
>>> "11.883 11.883 11.883 11.883"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex:

```py
import re

# this is what you'll have after you read the file, for example
text = "2*8.17997 723.188 4*33.33 3*11.0524"

matches = re.findall(r'(\d+\*)?(\d+\.\d+)', text)
# matches = [('2*', '8.17997'), ('', '723.188'), ('4*', '33.33'), ('3*', '11.0524')]

output = []
for match in matches:
    if match[0]:
        times = int(match[0][:-1])  # remove the `*`
    else:
        times = 1  # no `x*y` means one time y
    for _ in range(times):
        output.append(match[1])

output_str = ' '.join(output)
# output_str = '8.17997 8.17997 723.188 33.33 33.33 33.33 33.33 11.0524 11.0524 11.0524'
```

This code is not very nice, it's just so you understand the idea. The interesting part here is the regex. You can see more details here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion, how it would change if instead of inserting the values as (text=) I want the code to take the data from a text file, maybe f = open('OUT2.txt') and then to write it out to another text file after doing the changes (OUT3.txt). Thanks!